# Swing: Visual interface connect to second frame

Tags: java, swing

I have 2 frames. I want from the first frame to open the second. I tried this, but it leads to an exception.

```
class aboutaction implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.dispose();
            aboutInfo about = new aboutInfo();
            about.frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
about.addActionListener(new aboutaction());
```

This is the full program: https://github.com/Zhelyazkov97/Fuel-calculator.git.

Comment: What exception are you seeing?

Comment: at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: If i delete this from the second frame  "JFrame frame";
and write 
 about.setVisible(true); 
i open the frame but its not centered and not filled with menu bottons as the original file.

Comment: Should I take a guess and say, `about.frame` is `null` (and from the sounds of it `AboutInfo` extends `JFrame` anyway

Comment: @kriszhelyazkov: you should edit your questions and add the stack trace to it, not as comments.

Answer (score 2):

You're basic problem is a `NullPointerException` create from a misunderstanding of how Swing works and a bad design.

Basically, you define your class as...

```
public class aboutInfo extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    javax.swing.JFrame frame;
```

Now, here the confusion starts, you basically have two frames, but you only ever add components to the instance of `aboutInfo`.

The basic answer here is, get rid of `frame`, it's just confusing the issue.  In fact, you shouldn't be extending from `JFrame` in the first place, you should really use something like `JPanel` and simply add instances of the class to instances of `JFrame` or `JDialog` or what ever container you want